# Не могу разобраться с отображением названия приложения в андройд студио

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: На второй картинке изображен пустой экран,которяй я не могу изменить][image: Вот часть кода,но при просмотре дизайна у меня лишь пустой экран.Хочется чтобы вверху было написано "Color Description"]Вчера начал изучать ангройд студио,но не могу понять почему вверху не отображается название приложения.
Вверху “приложения”. На первой прикрепленной картинке есть два экрана. Черный и голубой. Я хотел бы,чтобы вверху отображалось нaзвание приложения “Color Description”(Вверху импровизированного экрана, куда я стараюсь прикрепить спиннер. Но так как названия нeт,то я на картинке креплю его просто на верх), но не выходит, oстается вот такая пустота В чем ошибка?

Comment: В каком таком "верху", уточните. (кнопка "править" под вопросом)

Comment: Вверху “приложения”. На первой прикрепленной картинке есть два экрана. Белый и голубой. Я хотел бы,чтобы вверху отображалось нзвание приложения “Color Description”, но не выходит, oстается вот такая пустота .

Comment: Вносите уточнения в тело вопроса, пожалуйста. Кнопка "править" под вопросом.

Comment: В правом верхнем углу вкладки дизайна есть три кнопки (Code / Split / Design). У Вас выбран Design, чтобы понимать, что Вы там сделали нужно выбрать Code, или хотя бы Split

Comment: Если я правильно понял, Вам надо добавить элемент Toolbar выше спиннера

Comment: Чтобы что-то отображалось, нужно это что-то отобразить. Какая часть кода здесь это делает?

Comment: Возможно вы путаете превью разметки и то, что на девайсе отобрзится. У вас в превью указано отображать без ActionBar, который указан в стилях и может быть отображён на девайсе. Проверьте как оно выглядит не в превью а на девайсе/эмуляторе.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще отображение заголовка зависит от нескольких условий.
По дефолту он отображается только в `ActionBar/ToolBar`, при чём текст его берётся из соответствующих атрибутов манифеста, если они заданы.

У вас же в превью выбрана тема с суффиксом "NoActionBar" (смотрите в панели над окошком превью) - это значит что панели заголовка нет вообще, переключите на другую тему и возможно увидите вожделенный текст.

**НО!!!** - превью в студии не поддерживает все возможности Android-UI и только на реальном устройстве вы увидите как оно будет выглядеть на самом деле, при чём на разных устройствах могут быть свои "нежданчики"
Поэтому превью - это чисто для того чтобы быстро и приблизительно набросать разметку и заценить дизайн (заказчику, например, сунуть на одобрение).
А всё досконально шлифовать уже надо тестируя на куче устройств или хотя бы эмуляторе в разных конфигурациях.